# Switch to second (build in) laptop battery if capacity is under 20%?

Tags: linux, power-management, laptop, battery

I got my new Lenovo T480 laptop which has two batteries: one internal and one external. The used Linux is Arch Linux.

If I use the battery the behavior is that the first battery is used down to 5% capacity and at this moment the second battery powers the laptop.

I want to change the value from 5% to 20% because using the battery down to 5% is in my opinion not the best way to get a healthy and long living battery.

With tlp I found a way to optimize the charging threshold. But at the moment I find existing no way to tell linux (or the notebook in general) to switch to the second battery if the first is under 20% capacity.

Is there any existing solution/best practice in the community? Otherwise I must build an own service which checks the battery every 5 minutes and switch manually via tlp and `force_discharge` (if it is possible).

Comment: AFAIR, the switch between batteries is made by hardware, not way to switch them via software.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro That can't be true; I've observed different behavior under Linux and Windows.

Comment: Did you found any resolve?